# Making a function affect other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to know how to access a function with another function. So if I have the code below, the change function does not affect the loader function. What am I doing wrong ?

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load( "test.js", function(geometry, materials){
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
scene.add(mesh);
});

  $('input').change(function() {

    if($("#radio").is(":checked")){
    mesh.material.materials[ 0 ].color.set( 0xff0000 );
    mesh.material.materials[ 1 ].color.set( 0x111111 );
  }

  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables of a function can not be accessed from other functions. Because javascript functions are [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), you can have a variable shared by both functions:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var mesh;

loader.load( "test.js", function(geometry, materials){
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
  scene.add(mesh);
});

$('input').change(function() {
  if($("#radio").is(":checked")){
    mesh.material.materials[ 0 ].color.set( 0xff0000 );
    mesh.material.materials[ 1 ].color.set( 0x111111 );
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes. Think of functions (closures) as having public and private scope.